# changes to database fail to update - visual basic

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I am having a problem getting my scores from my blackjack game to update to the Scores table in my Scoreboard database. When I click save score it does add the current users name and score to the ScoresDataGridView as it should but when I close the application and check the database no changes are made. I havent been able to figure this out. any help would be great. thanks.

```
Private Sub ButtonSaveScore_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
ButtonSaveScore.Click

    ScoresBindingSource.MoveLast()

    Dim scoreRow As ScoreboardDataSet.ScoresRow
    scoreRow = Me.ScoreboardDataSet.Scores.NewScoresRow()
    scoreRow.UserName = LabelPlayerName.Text
    scoreRow.Score = LabelWinsCounter.Text

    Me.ScoreboardDataSet.Scores.Rows.Add(scoreRow)

    Me.ScoresTableAdapter.Update(Me.ScoreboardDataSet)


    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.ScoresBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ScoreboardDataSet)
        MsgBox("Update successful")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Update failed")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add a proper tag for programming language used.

Comment: What does the TableAdapter Update and Insert queries look like?  Why are you updating the Score table directly, then calling UpdateAll for the entire dataset, isn't that a bit redundant?

Comment: When you re-open the application are the changes still there?

Comment: no the changes are never saved, within the application or to the database. each time the application is restarted the database reverts back to the original input.

Comment: I tried to make the changes both ways because neither one seemed to work. I am new to table adapters and working with a database. My program seems to make changes to the database when it is running but they are never saved.